# How do you check a checkbox once user starts typing in a textfield? And also uncheck the checkbox if textfield is empty in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, grails

So I have some code that checks the checkbox once the user starts typing in the textfield but I can't get it to uncheck if the user decides to erase everything he or she started typing and leave the textfield empty. Any help? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkvalue(val)
    {
        if(val.value == '')
            document.getElementById('productCB').checked="false"
        else
            document.getElementById('productCB').checked="true"
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <g:checkBox id="productCB" value="searchProduct" /> Product:
  <g:textField id="productID" placeholder="Enter product here..." onkeypress="checkvalue(this)" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`false` and `true` are booleans, not strings, and as such just checking the values length compared against zero will give the same result, a boolean.

You should also be using the onkeyup event for this :

```
<html>
<head> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkvalue(val) {
        document.getElementById('productCB').checked = val.value.trim().length > 0;
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkBox" id="productCB" value="searchProduct" /> Product:
  <input type="text" id="productID" placeholder="Enter product here..." onkeyup="checkvalue(this)" />
</body>
</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ykRnp/2/)

Comment: Of course, a space is input, do you wan't to remove empty spaces as well ?

Comment: Spaces are considered as input so that is fine. But this is exactly what I needed. Thank you! ps: Give me 3 minutes to accept the answer. I cant right now.

Comment: Note that *trim* is ES5 so a shim is required for non–ES5 browsers.